# WriteStream stopping when RDD is empty

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, rdd, databricks-autoloader

I have an autoloader stream:

```
    
streaming_df = (
    spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
    .option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", checkpoint_path) \
    .option("cloudFiles.format", "avro")
    .load(source_path)
)
json_string_df = streaming_df.select(col('Body').cast('string'),col('yearmonth'))

json_string_df.writeStream.foreachBatch(process_batch).option("mergeSchema", "true").option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path).trigger(once=True).start().awaitTermination()
```

At certain times of the day I get an Avro file that has an error message instead of the Body column. When trying to work in these files I get the error :

```
[STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = ed67a3a0-7b55-4bbf-b0cc-b5c88868c201, runId = b609c0a0-57bb-4359-848f-75f28c9468da] terminated with exception: An exception was raised by the Python Proxy. Return Message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/clientserver.py", line 617, in _call_proxy
    return_value = getattr(self.pool[obj_id], method)(*params)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 119, in call
    raise e
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 116, in call
    self.func(DataFrame(jdf, wrapped_session_jdf), batch_id)
  File "", line 18, in process_batch
    raw_ingestion_function(df, epoch_id)
  File "", line 23, in raw_ingestion_function
    df
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 113, in toDF
    return sparkSession.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py", line 48, in wrapper
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 1216, in createDataFrame
    return self._create_dataframe(
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 1264, in _create_dataframe
    rdd, struct = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 834, in _createFromRDD
    struct = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio, names=schema)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 780, in _inferSchema
    first = rdd.first()
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/instrumentation_utils.py", line 43, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2895, in first
    raise ValueError("RDD is empty")
ValueError: RDD is empty
```

I tried to solve this by adding a control in the `process_batch` function:

```
def process_batch(df, epoch_id):
    if not df.rdd.isEmpty():
        #function that create the result pyspark dataframe 
        raw_ingestion_function(df, epoch_id)
```

But it throws me the same exception. The main problem is that the exception continues to be thrown in subsequent run until I restart the checkpoint

Is there a way to skip empty rdd? Or to at least get the run after the error to work?